# How do add a custom setting for List?

Tags: 2010, list

it is possible to store custom settings (configuration) on a SharePoint.

Means : I have a configuration that add to General Settings List . I set up my settings for this list.

**Edit :**

I use the feature to implement a custom action.
Change the Elements.xml file of the Feature to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
Id="Custom.Configuration.ListCustomSettings"
GroupId="GeneralSettings"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
Sequence="100"
Title="Custom Settings">
<UrlAction
Url="_layouts/ListCustomSettings/ListSetting.aspx?List={ListId}" />
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

The next step is to create a custom page which we can redirect to and on which we can mange the custom settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with a custom action. Use "Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit" as custom location and "GeneralSettings" as groupid. There you can set the path to you custom settingspage.

Samplecode:

```
  <CustomAction Id="Custom.Configuration.ListCustomSettings"
                GroupId="GeneralSettings"
                Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
                RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
                Sequence="100"
                Title="Custom Settings">
    <UrlAction Url="_layouts/ListCustomSettings/ListSetting.aspx?List={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
```

To save the custom properties use:

```
SPContext.Current.List.RootFolder.Properties[strPropertyKey] = strValue;
SPContext.Current.List.RootFolder.Update();
```

And to read them:

```
strValue = SPContext.Current.List.RootFolder.Properties[strPropertyKey].ToString();
```